# Protractor use sendKeys() to upload a file in a <div>

Tags: angularjs, upload, drag-and-drop, protractor

As you can see in the title, I am trying to upload a file using protractor.
In my project, I have a webpage where I can drag & drop a file, using resumable.js assigned to a div representing the drop area.

The fact is, when doing e2e testing, I obviously can't drag & drop a file, so I chose to upload it using `sendKeys()` with the absolute path of my file `path.resolve('./tests', 'test.csv')`.

Until here, everything works (path is good and I can find my element with `element(by.id(...))` but when I use `sendKeys()` it throws an error saying `"unknown error: cannot focus element"`.

I tried to upload on an `<input type="file"></input>`, it works, but since it's on what I use I can't upload this on my original div.

I think I have to specify that this is a file, I saw the `setFileDetector(detector)` function but I am not sure this is the right way to proceed, and it doesn't seem to work with it anyway.

Here is the HTML drag & drop :

```
<p translate>Drag & Drop your file below</p>
<div class="drop" ng-class="dropClass" id="import-drop-area" data-ng-init="init()" translate>&nbsp;</div>
```

And here is the test that works on an  but not on my div :

```
it('Should begin the import wizard by dropping a file', function(done) {

    // Begin the wizard
    var nextButton = element(by.id('next'));
    nextButton.click();

    // Upload a file
    var uploadArea = element(by.id('import-drop-area'));
    var file = path.resolve('./tests/import', 'test.csv');
    uploadArea.sendKeys(file);
    setTimeout(done, 1000);
});
```

I hope someone could help me, thank you by advance !

Best regards.

Comment: Could you show the HTML markup of the block where the drag and drop is performed including the file input itself? Is it visible?

Comment: Hello, I edited my message, you can now see the code used ! Yes it is visible, I don't have any errors when I do `var uploadArea = element(by.id('import-drop-area'));`

Comment: Thanks, can you actually see the file input itself in the DOM? (may be it is in the [shadow dow](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-shadow-dom/)..)

Comment: I am not sure to understand what do you mean about this... There is no actual input, it's just a div in which I append an absolute path detected as a file (drag & drop). So I'm not sure this is a shadow dom either, but I am not fully aware about it.

Comment: Could you provide us with a reproducible example so that we can also see the problem? Thanks.